# how to create a real time Simulink transfer block

Tags: tcp, transfer, simulink

I have a simple idea but I guess it's hard to implement it on simulink. I created a TCP/IP server between a BeagleBone and a simulink block using C code. I have a switch connected to the beagle bone as an input and my idea is to have a display on the simulink block showing if the switch is close or open. I couldn't do it because my client(simulink block) is a c code and it will do the job only once as C code ends the function execution after return to get the value of the switch. Do you guys know any simulink transfer mode or fancy C tip to transfer data between the Simulink client block and the display ?

Answer (score 0):

In a simulator I've been working on we used a Sink block with remote IP address and IP port to export the data calculated at real time to an external listener (this could be on the same machine or connected via network) which in our case was a computer doing the graphics rendering, which was then picked up by a C++ code written using Ogre 3D and by another simulink model using a source block.

We also had an interactive chartplotter display (GPS position indication, if you will). We could access the values generated from simulink by calling the following command any time it was needed:

```
variable = get_param('Simulator/Chartplotter/YDot','RuntimeObject');
```

You could also call "set_param" to modify a constant value located inside the simulink model.

I don't have experience in beagle but I imagine you could have your C code execute a matlab scrip which would modify a logical constant present in your simulink model to indicate whether the switch is open or not.

Alternatively you could explore the first option but we only used it to get data out of simulink into the C program, not the other way around as you'd wish to do. I haven't got direct access to the receiving C code unfortunately but if you are really stuck I could ask my colleagues to send me the important bits.

Hope this helps.